# Python convert tuple into string

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
date = [2, 5, 2018]
text = "%s/%s/%s" % tuple(date)
print(text)
```

It gives result `2/5/2018`.How to convert it like `02/05/2018`

Answer (score 2):

```
text = "{:02d}/{:02d}/{:d}".format(*date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.zfill(2)` to pad your date pieces with 2 leading zeros:

```
date = [2, 5, 2018]
text = "%s/%s/%s" % tuple([str(date_part).zfill(2) for date_part in date])
print(text) # Outputs: 02/05/2018
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date = [2, 5, 2018]
text = "{:0>2}/{:0>2}/{}".format(*date)
print(text)
```

to learn more about using `format`, read: https://pyformat.info/